# Structural Topic Model (STM) Error: UNRELIABLE VALUE: Future (‘<none>’) unexpectedly generated random numbers without specifying argument 'seed'

Tags: r, error-handling, topic-modeling, topicmodels

After running my stm several times successfully, I now get this error message every time I try to run it:

```
UNRELIABLE VALUE: Future (‘<none>’) unexpectedly generated random numbers without specifying argument 'seed'. There is a risk that those random numbers are not statistically sound and the overall results might be invalid. To fix this, specify 'seed=TRUE'. This ensures that proper, parallel-safe random numbers are produced via the L'Ecuyer-CMRG method. To disable this check, use 'seed=NULL', or set option 'future.rng.onMisuse' to "ignore".
```

This is the code I ran:

```
many_models <- data_frame(K = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)) %>%
mutate(topic_model = future_map_dbl(K, ~stm(tweet_df_sparse, K = .,
verbose = FALSE)))
```

Any idea how to quickly fix it?

Comment: I encountered the same issue. This link may help https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/09/future-1-19-1-making-sure-proper-random-numbers-are-produced-in-parallel-processing/

Answer (score 6):

Need to add seed = TRUE to future_map_dbl()

```
many_models <- data_frame(K = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)) %>%
mutate(topic_model = future_map(future_map_dbl(K, ~stm(tweet_df_sparse, K = ., verbose = FALSE, .options = furrr_options(seed = T)))
```

Comment: I love R, but how was I ever supposed to figure out that `.options = furrr_options(seed = TRUE)` was the right argument to pass from the above error message?

Comment: Did you pass it to `stm()` or `future_map()`?